# Datepicker - separate YY and MM only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm trying to have two separate fields for YY and MM 
What I have right now is more or less what I want except it's only one field. Here's how it looks like now: [how it's looking right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci8h9.png)

```
 <input id="residenceyears" name="residenceyears" type="text"    placeholder="YY/MM" class="input yyMM numeric-only">
```

This is the JS function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.yyMM').datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 monthNames: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"],
 yearRange: "-100:+0", 
 dateFormat: 'yy/mm',

 onClose: function() {
    var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
 },

 beforeShow: function() {
   if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) 
   {
      iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
      iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
      $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
       $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
   }
}
```

});

What I'm trying to achieve is this: [it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8jJN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/mLcpwdra/

The code:

*html*

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<hr />
<div id="month"><p>Month:<span></span></p></div>
<div id="year"><p>Year:<span></span></p></div>
<div id="day"><p>Day:<span></span></p></div>
```

*js*

```
var obj = {
    init: function()
  {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect : function(date_string,instance)
      {
        var date_obj = new Date(date_string);
        $('#month span').text(String("00"+date_obj.getMonth()).slice(-2));
        $('#year span').text(date_obj.getFullYear());
        $('#day span').text(String("00"+date_obj.getDate()).slice(-2));
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    obj.init();
});
```

It's a starting point, but think fits your needs. Hope this helps

**UPDATE**: Fiddle with year in YY "format" -> https://jsfiddle.net/mLcpwdra/1/

Comment: That is not user friendly. User has to manually clicking the arrows to get to the year they want instead of selecting it.

Comment: **I point out this is a starting point**. You can play with datepicker options by yourself to fine tuning it. I think my fiddle shows you how to manage datestring into object and set that data into a dom element correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the approach to your requirement, but does not solves it exactly.

Here goes the HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="yearMonthInput"></select>
```

Here goes the javascript:

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    for (i = new Date().getFullYear() ; i > 2008; i--) {
        $.each(months, function (index, value) {
            $('#yearMonthInput').append($('<option />').val(index + "_" + i).html(i + " " + value));
        });                
    }
```

Give it a try! though it is not exactly what you are looking for.